# bs-sortable selection on perticular item selecting complete grid while dragging

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I have implemented bs-sortable using below link ,functionality is working as per expectation , but I am facing problem with drag-drop,when i am trying to select one element in grid and drop it complete grid is getting selected while dragging .

Comment: i have refereed this page  > https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/sortable#itemTemplate

Comment: Do you have the code you have tried and not working?

Comment: <bs-sortable
       [(ngModel)]="categorie"         
       [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"        
       (dragend)="cancelEvent1($event)"
       itemClass="box"
       itemActiveClass="sortable-item-active"       
       wrapperClass="sortable-wrapper">
        </bs-sortable>   
        
        <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item="item"  let-index="index" >
          <div class="col-sm-3 box" >          
                <em class="material-icons add-icon"  >{{ item.value.icon }}</em>                                    
          </div>
        </ng-template>